# How to insert async and defer in script tags with CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using PHP Framework CakePHP 3.0.3 and would like to know how to insert the keywords **defer** and **async** script tags:

How is the Script Injection with the framework:

```
 <? = $ This-> html-> script ('jquery-1.11.1.min.js')?>
```

How is rendered:

```
 <script src = "/ js / jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </ script>
```

Like how you would like it to be:

```
 <async script src = "/ js / jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </ script> 
 <script defer src = "/ js / jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </ script>
```

In the documentation I saw nothing that could be done this insert.

An alternate form is to make as follows:

```
 <? = $ This-> html-> script ('jquery-1.11.1.min.js' ['defer' => true])?>
```

and this rendering:

```
 <script src = "/ js / jquery-1.11.1.min.js" defer = "defer"> </ script>
```

Comment: So your actual question is how to render `defer` instead of `defer="defer"` (which btw makes no difference, functionality wise)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to do it with `$this->Html->script()` function. This is hard coded in Cake\View\StringTemplate. I suggest to just leave it as it is now, it will work anyway.
If it's vital issue for you try override HtmlHelper and implement your own script() function.

Answer (score 5):

This one works for me.

```
<?= $this->html->script('jquery-1.11.1.min.js', ['async']);?>
```

After

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" async="async"></script>
```